# Клиентские и серверные сокеты

Tags: java

После краткого ознакомления с сокетами по "Head first java" пытаюсь подключить клиента к серверу (в будущем хочу попробовать реализовать чат), но ничего не получается. Можете пояснить, почему метод accept блокирует потоки и программа "зависает"?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

    private final static int port = 4242;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            if(socket.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Socket connected");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер в текущем потоке ожидает входящие соединения.
Что бы программа "отвисла", создайте класс и запустите во время запущенного сервера:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4242);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Можно даже в 1 классе

```
public class ClientServerEdu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Server()).start();
        new Thread(new Client()).start();
    }

    private static class Server implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4242);

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    System.out.println("Client connected");
                }
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Client implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4242);
                System.out.println("Connection with server created");
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```